# Could Harry turn into an obscurus, if Dursleys were successful in keeping him away from Hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, obscurus

Given the fact that Dursleys were cruel towards Harry and didn't ever want him to know that he is a wizard. If they were somehow successful in keeping him away from Hogwarts, I wonder would it be possible that Harry's magical powers if continuously suppressed by Dursleys turned him into an obscurus?

Answer (score 8):

I found this in the FAQs section of [JKR's personal website](https://www.jkrowling.com/welcome-to-my-new-website/).

> **Why didn’t Harry Potter develop an Obscurus? An Obscurus is developed under very specific conditions: trauma associated with the
>   use of magic, internalized hatred of one’s own magic and a conscious
>   attempt to suppress it.**
>
> *JKR: The Dursleys were too frightened of magic ever to acknowledge its
>   existence to Harry. While Vernon and Petunia had a confused hope that
>   if they were nasty enough to Harry his strange abilities might somehow
>   evaporate, they never taught him to be ashamed or afraid of magic.
>   Even when he was scolded for ‘making things happen’, he didn’t make
>   any attempt to suppress his true nature, nor did he ever imagine that
>   he had the power to do so.*

Comment: That's a reasonable find but might I suggest you dump the wiki commentary and just post the JKR quote. Their intrusion in your answer adds nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll do that right now :)